# How to require permissions to be enabled in Firefox using Manifest v3?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, manifest.json

As of January 17, Firefox now supports Manifest v3 in [Firefox 109.0](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/109.0/releasenotes/).

I have an add-on I am testing with Manifest v3 and it requires access to a variable on reddit.com.

I want to make the "Access your data for sites in the *://reddit.com domain" permission **required**, since the extension does not work without it.

What needs to be done to make it so it does **not** show as optional since I want the user to not have to explicitly turn on the permission from the Permissions tab?

[image]

I want it show as required similar to this image ([source](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/manage-optional-permissions-extensions)):

[image]

Here's a trimmed down version of an example Manifest file that shows the permission as optional.

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Example",
    "description": "Example",
    "version": "3.16.1",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "run_at": "document_idle",
            "matches": ["*://*.reddit.com/"],
            "js": ["script.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried adding `"permissions": ["https://*.reddit.com/*"]`, but it still shows as optional.

I also tried `"permissions": ["*://reddit.com"]` and `"host_permissions": ["*://reddit.com"]` but nothing is causing it to be required.

I have a Chrome extension which is working with the same manifest v3 file.

Comment: This is probably a bug in Firefox or maybe they misunderstood that Chrome's plan for ManifestV3 was to allow the user choose when installing the extension whether to grant the required host permissions immediately or make them optional. This feature is not yet implemented in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I have found is to set optional permissions.
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/permissions/

I added the permission setting itself to the listener. Of course, I check beforehand that such permissions do not already exist.

```
    browser.action.onClicked.addListener((tab: Tab) => {
      browser.permissions.request({
        origins: ['*://*.reddit.com/']
      })
    });
```

Comment: Warning: if you have `action.default_popup` in manifest.json, `browser.action.onClicked` is never called. Hopefully I spared somebody else's time wandering around stackoverflow and MDN trying to figure out why `browser.action.onClicked` is never f*****g called!

Comment: Where should I copy paste your code? manifest.json ?

Comment: @Alex01 You need to add it to background script